# positional arguments python crash course?

Tags: python, arguments, keyword-argument, arbitrary-values, positional-argument

```
def build_profile(first, last, **user_info):
"""Build a dictionary containing everything we know about a user."""
user_info['first_name'] = first
user_info['last_name'] = last
return user_info


user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein',
                        location='princeton',
                        field='physics')
print(user_profile)
```

Output:

`{'location': 'princeton', 'field': 'physics', 'first_name': 'albert', 'last_name': 'einstein'}`

**I dont understand why the key and value first_name and last_name was placed at the last? aren't they supposed to be placed before location and field? because of positional arguments??**

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you'd want the positional arguments passed in to the function to come before the `**kwargs` passed in, you could use the `dict(..., **kwargs)` approach to build a new `dict` object:

```py
def build_profile(first, last, **addl_info):
    """Build a dictionary containing everything we know about a user."""
    user_info = {'first_name': first, 'last_name': last, **addl_info}
    return user_info


user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein',
                             location='princeton',
                             field='physics')
print(user_profile)
```

Out:

```
{'first_name': 'albert', 'last_name': 'einstein', 'location': 'princeton', 'field': 'physics'}
```

Comment: im still trying to understand, since (first and last ) were placed first inside the parameter, and we return the user_info, and then when you build the profile, we call albert and einstein first, why is the ouput showing key value pairs at the last?

Comment: If you mean why are the `**kwarg` parts at the end (location and field), I believe thats due to the order we're passing them in to the constructor. That is, we're passing `dict(first, last, **kwargs)` rather than trying to update the `kwargs` object, which already has the keys location and field in our case.